# Editar un Excel con Python openpyxl usando inputs

Tags: python, excel, input, openpyxl

estoy aprendiendo a programar en pyhton y quiero editar un archivo Excel usando inputs, para strs no hay problema, se guardan correctamente en el archivo cuando lo corro, pero quiero que en un  input solo se puedan ingresar numeros osea un : "int(input(""))y que no se termine el programa cuando salga el valueError.Mi codigo no funciona, he intentado con ciclos y nunca terminan, Como logro que funcione? (solo puedo usar python 3.8 y openpyxl) Tambien me gustaria saber si puedo hacer operaciones simples como multiplicaciones, gracias.

```
ciclo=1
while  ciclo==1:
  try:
    sheet['B5'] = int(input("Introduce numeros")) 
    if sheet['B5'] is [1234567890]:
      print('guardando')
      ciclo==2
   
  except ValueError:
    print("utiliza solo digitos")  

 wb2.save(archivos)
```

Comment: El código no funciona correctamente. Esa es la duda que nos presentas? Como arreglar el código para que funcione? Por que no preguntas nada, solo dices tu objetivo.

Comment: si, mi codigo no funciona, mi pregunta es : como logro que funcione ? ya intente hacer un ciclo while pero nunca termina, sale el "utiliza solo digitos" pero cuando uso numeros se repite infinitamente

Comment: No utilices `is` para comparar valores, utiliza `==`. Lo que hace `is` es comparar direcciones de memoria. Además verifica que lo que devuelve `sheet['B5']` sea una lista.

Comment: Como verifico que sea una lista?
Con el == aun sigue repitiéndose por siempre :C

Comment: imprime su valor y su tipo `print(sheet['B5'], type(sheet['B5']))`

Comment: `<Cell 'Sheet'.B5> <class 'openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell'>`

me aparece esto en la terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

El problema está en esta linea:

```
if sheet['B5'] is [1234567890]
```

Aquí preguntas si `sheet["b5"]`, que sería un objeto que representa una celda de excel, ES (distinto a "es igual", algo igual no necesariamente será eso mismo) una lista de un solo item, el cual es el numero `1234567890`.

Esto siempre es falso, ya que ambas cosas no son lo mismo.

#### Solución

Me tomé la molestia de reescribir tu código para mejorarlo, espero que te sirva:

```
import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook("prueba.xlsx")

# Esto crea un bucle infinito, aunque podemos usar break para terminar con dicho bucle
while True:
    # colocamos la menor cantidad de código posible dentro del try
    # esto disminuirá la posibilidad de que ocurra un error inesperado
    # y el programa diga "Por favor ingrese un numero" cuando no debería.
    try:
        valor = int(input("Introduce numeros"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Por favor ingrese un numero")

        # con esto le decimos a Python que queremos volver al principio del bucle while sin ejecutar el resto del bloque
        continue

    if(valor < 0 or valor > 9):
        print("El numero debe estar entre 0 y 9")
        continue

    # si todo sale bien, rompemos el bucle while infinito
    break
    
sheet['B5'] = valor

print("guardando...")

wb2.save("prueba2.xlsx")
```

Además, hice que el valor no se agregue a la celda a menos de que el valor ingresado sea el correcto. El código original modificaba la celda incluso si el número no estaba en el rango esperado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya funciona! :D te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: De nada Neye :D

Comment: Edité la respuesta. Puse un and donde debía haber un or y ya lo corregí.

Comment: Igual me sirve asi Jajajaja queria poder poner numeros como 42 , muchas gracias :D